# Римские и арабские цифры

Tags: числительные, цифры

Когда нужно писать номера римскими цифрами, а когда арабскими?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Принято считать, что римские цифры больше относятся к порядковым числительным, а арабские - в количественным. Так, некрасиво будет написать "я купил III яблока" или "Решения 25 съезда КПССС - в жизнь!"
Таким образом, когда речь идет о количестве чего-то, а также о датах и времени, следует писать арабские цифра, а если - о порядковом номере, то римские.
Примеры: *Петр III, 1 января, XXV съезд КПСС, 3 яблока*.

Answer (score 1):

Интересно, номера чего именно? Если речь идёт о сочинении, то века пишутся римскими, а годы и даты арабскими.

Comment: АРХАИЗМ. Малое число еще можно латинским способом, до  50 можно, а потом? 
Даже если знаешь, все равно без тренировки проблемы.MDCLXVI.
Интересно, Как это римляне торговали с такой  системой, не сложить в уме, не вычесть, компьютер надо,  АБАКУС. А может не торговали? Что-то не встречалось мне документов, где была бы записана торговая операция  таким способом.

Comment: Ну это зависит от некоторого навыка. Кому-то и по пальцам считать сложно. А римляне прекрасно торговали. дело привычки. Для серьезных вычислений их цифры действительно не фонтан, но все ж получше, чем те же греко-славяснкие. А ими на Руси до Петра пользовались - да и после...

Comment: Ну, попробуйте, приобретите навык.
Ими церковь пользовалась, поэтому латинская манера--каждой выбранной букве- число, отразилась в кирилловской азбуке. Кирилл между прочим, святой латинской церкви-католической, а за что?
Там в кириллице система нумерации таже, расширили номенклатуру, да еще и буквы пропущены б и ж, почему, а их нет в латинском.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Старославянская_азбука
нет и еще более десяти букв.
И это все при том, что даже в новгородских грамотах русские люди уже давно пользовались десятичной позиционной системой и писали словами, осмьнадцать, а не буквами.

Comment: Буквами-цифрами писали только в летописи, монахи. 
Второе, торговлей монахи точно не занимались,  жили на подаяния.
и см. четки https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%B8%F2%EA%E8
а затем смотрим четки в словарях латинском--Rosarium ну, прямо розами запахло, а может каким другим духом? или они цветочки на клумбах считали, хорошее занятие.
знамо каким, славянским.  ružičnjak-в хорватском то осталось. 
ну, а дальше вопросы к историкам и кто писал историю.

Answer (score 1):

Римские цифры традиционно используются в указании веков (чаще - нашей эры), номеров событий (фестивалей, съездов, чемпионатов), иногда - томов собраний сочинений и выпусков журналов и альманахов, цифр на механических часах и т.п.
Ранее использовавшееся обозначение месяца римскими цифрами сейчас совершенно вышло из употребления и нарушает современные стандарты.   
Таким образом, обычное употребление римских цифр ограничено порядковыми числительными, но и там их область весьма узка. 
Если сомневаетесь, пишите арабскими, это не ошибка. А вот писать римскими цифрами то, что не следует, - ошибка и грубая.